# VIM - how to replace a line with contents of yank register?

Tags: vim, text

I normally copy a line pressing 'y' key twice, then pressing 'p' or 'P' to paste after or before a current line, respectively. Sometimes, however I need to replace a current line with the yanked line. How to do it?

Comment: Personally I'd just do `pkdd`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Pasting over a visual selection should work: <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>

(<kbd>V</kbd> to select the entire line visually, <kbd>p</kbd> to replace it with the contents of the default register).

Comment: Whoah. Never knew you could do that!

Comment: Nice, you've just saved me a few extra minutes per year! Only thing to note is that the contents of the default register are replaced.

Comment: nice solution, requires only 3 keys (Shift, V, then p)!

Comment: A slightly safer version would be: `V"0p`, which pastes from the yank register instead of the default register. As Mr E noted, the visual selection overwrites the default register, so if you ran `Vp` twice it might produce different results each time.

Comment: Good thinking, nelstrom. I am forever putting brevity ahead of safety!

Comment: This answer should be updated (with credits) according to the comment by @nelstrom

Answer (score 5):

You can delete the current line without replacing your copied/yanked line with `"_dd`.

Comment: Yes - I saw it on a forum a while back. Prince Goulash has a much better solution though!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line before or after yanking the (possibly named) buffer.  Delete after if you didn't name yank into a named buffer - or use `"2P` (or `"2p`) to yank the second buffer if you delete first.

Comment: it is slow, Prince Goulash has nicer solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also just turn off the buffer-overwrite side-effect behavior as needed by putting this script in your .vimrc

[vim toggling buffer overwrite behavior when deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625722/vim-toggling-buffer-overwrite-behavior-when-deleting)

Then you can toggle the overwrite behavior using key combo ,, (two commas)